# How to make a scatter plot with different experiments all in one graph for comparison and all lines of best fit are included using R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I try to create a scatter plot with four different variables: SMX with E.coli, SMX with S.aureus, TMP with E.coli, TMP with S. aureus. I am a beginner in R. I can create the graph in Excel like this:

[image]

But I got asked specifically to create the graph in R studio. I've already spent a week trying to create this graph, but it still does not work at the end. Can someone help me with the graph please? Thank you.

The dataset in R:

```
dput(Bacteria)
structure(list(`Log [antibiotic concentration] (log(µg/µl))` = c(0, 
0.301029996, 0.602059991, 0.77815125, 0.903089987, 1, 0, -0.698970004, 
-0.397940009, -0.22184875, -0.096910013, 0, 0, -1, -0.698970004, 
-0.522878745, -0.397940009, -0.301029996, 0, 0, 0.301029996, 
0.477121255, 0.602059991, 0.698970004), `Mean Absorbance` = c(0.3925, 
0.375, 0.388, 0.358, 0.357, 0.4115, 0.3465, 0.299, 0.2805, 0.2895, 
0.3495, 0.4585, 0.3975, 0.405, 0.404, 0.404, 0.4105, 0.474, 0.3975, 
0.405, 0.404, 0.404, 0.4105, 0.474), Experiment = c("SMX with E. coli", 
"SMX with E. coli", "SMX with E. coli", "SMX with E. coli", "SMX with E. coli", 
"SMX with E. coli", "SMx with S. aureus", "SMx with S. aureus", 
"SMx with S. aureus", "SMx with S. aureus", "SMx with S. aureus", 
"SMx with S. aureus", "TMP with E . coli", "TMP with E . coli", 
"TMP with E . coli", "TMP with E . coli", "TMP with E . coli", 
"TMP with E . coli", "TMP with S. aureus", "TMP with S. aureus", 
"TMP with S. aureus", "TMP with S. aureus", "TMP with S. aureus", 
"TMP with S. aureus")), .Names = c("Log [antibiotic concentration] (log(µg/µl))", 
"Mean Absorbance", "Experiment"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I cannot 'read' your sample-data in R.

Comment: *I've already spent a week trying to create this graph but it still does not work at the end* ... where is your trials and show us what does not work -errors/undesired results? Otherwise, this sounds like a request for code-writing which StackOverflow is not.

Comment: @Wimpel ... load `dplyr` and then assign `dput` to a variable: `Bacteria <- structure(...)`. OP posted a tibble and not base R dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect for ggplot2. Saved your data in `d` and renamed first column to `"Log"`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(Log, `Mean Absorbance`, color=Experiment)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F) +
  xlab("Log [antibiotic concentration] (log(µg/µl))") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]